# The volume and the surface area of a cylinder having base radius $r$ and height $h$ inscribed in a fixed sphere of radius $a$ as functions of ...

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, area, volume, spheres

We are given a sphere of radius $a$, and a cylinder of base radius $r$ and height $h$ is inscribed in this sphere.

How to express the volume and the surface area of the cylinder as functions of $r$? as functions of $h$?

My [Corrected] Attempt [Based on the correction by MathLover]:

> Any of the "diagonals" of the cylinder passes through the center of the sphere and thus has length $2a$. So we have the relation
> $$ 4r^2 + h^2 = 4a^2. \tag{1} $$

> So if we put $h = \sqrt{ 4a^2 - 4r^2 }= 2 \sqrt{ a^2 - r^2}$, then we obtain
> $$
> V = \pi r^2 h = 2\pi r^2 \sqrt{ a^2 - r^2 }, \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad S = 2 \pi rh = 4 \pi r \sqrt{ a^2 - r^2 }. 
> $$
> Thus both $V$ and $S$ are expressed as functions of $r$.

> From (1), we also obtain $r = \frac12 \sqrt{ 4a^2 - h^2}$, and thus we obtain
> $$
> V = \pi r^2 h = \frac14 \pi h \left( 4a^2 - h^2 \right), \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad S = 2 \pi r h = \pi h \sqrt{ 4a^2 - h^2},
> $$
> thus expressing $V$ and $S$ as functions of $h$.

Are my formulas correct? If so, is method applied by me in reaching these formulas also correct in each case? Or, are there instances where I have gone wrong?

Comment: @MathLover thank you very much for the correction. As per the Math SE rules, is it legittimate for me to incorporate the correction suggested by you directly into my original solution?

Comment: What makes me wonder is that a member with more than 20k reputation asked this kind of question.

Comment: MichaelHoppe you're right, but whenever I've run into such situations in the past, I've chosen to add a PS to my post instead of incorporating the correction(s) suggested in the comments directly into my solution itself.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you, was just wondering.  Your attempts are right, though.